# Fastest coding way to add rows to an ASP.net DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, dataset

What's the fastest way in term of speed of coding to add rows to a DataTable? I don't need to know neither the name of columns nor datatype. Is it possible to add rows without previously specify the number or name of dataTable columns?

```
        DataTable t = new DataTable();
        t.Rows.Add(value1,
            value1,
            value2,
            value3,
            ...
            valueN
            );
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(t);
```

Comment: `Fast`? in term of speed of execution, speed of coding, speed of rendering?

Comment: N values, string and decimals.

Comment: @SteveB Speed of coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input comes out of a  collection, you could loop it to create the `DataColumns` with the correct type:

```
var data = new Object[] { "A", 1, 'B', 2.3 };
DataTable t = new DataTable();
// create all DataColumns
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
    t.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column " + i, data[i].GetType()));
}
// add the row to the table
t.Rows.Add(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question:  no, you have to have columns defined on the table.  You can't just say, "Hey, make a column for all these values."  Nothing stopping you from creating columns on the fly, though, as Mr. Schmelter says.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the rows or columns (you first need to add columns, without that not possible)

```
 for(int intCount = 0;intCount < dt.Rows.Count; intCount++)
 {
  for(int intSubCount = 0; intSubCount < dt.Columns.Count; intSubCount++)
   {
         dt.Rows[intCount][intSubCount] = yourValue; // or assign to something
   }
 }
```